# Android ListView: Getting text of item without using click event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is there a way to get the value of `TextView` which is an item of a ListView without using any click event ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendNoTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friendImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendFullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friendImage"
        android:textColor="#0D47A1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addFriendButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_friend" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addFriendTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addFriendButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="ADD FRIEND"
        android:textColor="#0D47A1"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom row layout defined as above and i need to get the value of the `friendNoTv TextView`without any click event. I tried it as

```
@Override
public View getView(int index, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // check if we need to generate a new View from scratch or recycle one
    View InflatedView = convertView;
    if (InflatedView == null) {
        InflatedView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_friends_result_row, parent, false);
    }

    // setup variables

    final TextView friendNo = (TextView) InflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friendNoTv);
    ImageView friendImage = (ImageView) InflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friendImage);
    TextView friendFullName = (TextView) InflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friendFullName);
    ImageButton addFriendButton = (ImageButton) InflatedView.findViewById(R.id.addFriendButton);

    //Exception here, friendNo.getText().toString() comes up NULL
    final int friendId = Integer.parseInt(friendNo.getText().toString());

    if(isFriend(friendId)){
        addFriendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        addFriendButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //TODO

    Friend friend = friendList.get(index);

    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    friendNo.setText(Integer.toString(friend.getBorNo()));
    dataFormatter.decodeimage(friend.getUserImage(),friendImage);
    friendFullName.setText(friend.getFullName());

    return InflatedView;

}
```

But value comes up `Null` which causes an `Exception`. How do i fix this ? Any help would be appreiated.

Comment: Please post the code about the creation of the list

Comment: Updated @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: i mean the code in the activity where you create the list and where you call for the value, not the adapter :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley the list is full of data dont worry about it

Comment: i mean, it is because we need the method which calls for the list.. without i can't help you, maybe someone with more experience can :)

Comment: Null is happening because of not initializing values to **friendId**  .

Answer (score -1):

You are getting null because you just have inflated the view and you are trying to get the text before setting it. In your XML you haven't set any text value that's why you are getting nothing there.

Just replace that line which is giving null with below one,

```js
    final int friendId = Integer.parseInt(friendList.get(index).getFriendId.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code here:

```
//Exception here, friendNo.getText().toString() comes up NULL
 final int friendId = Integer.parseInt(friendNo.getText().toString());
```

will definitely be null as friendNo is not set yet. you should paste these line at last just before return statement with the conditional statement.